# Big array, problems echoing it out

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I got this problem trying to echo out a big array.

print_r looks like this:
http://codepaste.net/5js97a

There's no problem echoing out the first 2 rows like this in a foreach loop:
$item['name'], but for the rest of them deeper inside the array, I just get an error.

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
function categories($parent = NULL) {
      $query = $this->db->where('parent_id', $parent)->get('categories');
      $results = $query->result_array();

      foreach($results as $result) {
           $child_array = Forummodel::categories($result['id']);
           if(sizeof($child_array) == 0) {
                array_push($results, $result['name']);
           } else {
                array_push($results, array($result['name'], $child_array));
           }
      }

      return $results;
}
```

Im also using codeigniter

Comment: What error do you get, and what code did you use to get it? Arrays aren't broken, it's probably your code, and we can't fix it without knowing what it is :)

Comment: Um, can you show the code you're actually using?

Comment: function categories($parent = NULL)
    { 
  
  $query = $this
     ->db
      ->where('parent_id', $parent)
      ->get('categories');
  $results = $query->result_array();
  
  foreach($results as $result) {
            $child_array = Forummodel::categories($result['id']);
            if(sizeof($child_array) == 0) {
                array_push($results, $result['name']);
            } else {
                array_push($results, array($result['name'], $child_array));
            }
   
        }
  return $results;
 }

Im also using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating on an increasing array. Here is your code:

```
function categories($parent = NULL) {
    $query = $this ->db ->where('parent_id', $parent) ->get('categories');
    $results = $query->result_array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $child_array = Forummodel::categories($result['id']);
        if(sizeof($child_array) == 0) {
            array_push($results, $result['name']);
        } else {
            array_push($results, array($result['name'], $child_array));
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

The foreach is iterating down the array `$results` and you are adding to it with each loop, plus, by the time you hit an iteration where `$result` doesn't contain 'id' or 'name' you are probably getting the error. You might want to put the child arrays into another array and merge them after the foreach loop if you still want to do that.